# SIGSEV SPOJ(PRIME1)

Tags: c++, c++11

The problem I am solving is PRIME1 which says to print all the prime numbers between 2 numbers. Although the code I made runs properly on my compiler with the worst case as well, It gives me a SIGSEV error when compiling in SPOJ. Here is the code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define int long long
using namespace std;
signed main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t>0)
    {
        int a,b,n,p;
        cin>>a>>b;
            n = b-a;
            bool prime[n+1];
            memset(prime,true,sizeof(prime));

            for(p=2;p*p<=b;p++)
            {
                  if(prime[p]==true)
                  {
                        for(int i=p*2;i<=b;i+=p)
                        {
                              prime[i]=false;
                        }
                  }
            }

            (a==1)?p=2:p=a;
            for(p;p<=b;p++)
                  if(prime[p])
                        cout<<p<<endl;
            t--;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is SPOJ and how is it related to `c++`?

Comment: SPOJ is basically sphere online judge. A competitive programming practice platform. Since the code is in C++, hence it is related to C++.

Comment: http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/ Here is the link to the question

Comment: Waste of time Arpit. Waste of time.

Comment: @RawN Why's that?

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: `<bits/stdc++.h>` is an internal compiler header. You should include the proper standard headers instead. Also I don't think `#define int` is such a good idea... `signed main()` really?

Comment: `bool prime[n+1];` declares a Variable Length Array which is not standard in C++ and even in C should be used for small arrays.

Comment: BTW the conditional operator (usually) should be written as `p = a == 1 ? 2 : a;` and more importantly, you are accessing the prime array up to `b`, but its dimension is `n + 1` or `b - a + 1`.